# Is SSH required?

Tags: ssh, security

I didn't know anything about SSH prior to seeing the setting page (screenshot attached) after signing up in UbuntuOne and the forums and have since researched it and yet I'm left wondering whether it's required or useful. I found info indicating SSH can be a risk and I don't want to compromise my system. I'm brand new to Linux/Ubuntu. Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot of ssh feature in UbuntuOne accout settings]

Comment: please improve the question. You want to know if is required for using Ubuntu or for developing code with  Canonical services? You have two different answers bellow.

Answer (score 4):

In your UbuntuOne account the SSH keys are used for authentication to SSH-based Canonical services, e. g. a developer/contributor uploading a package file to the repositories.

Unless you belong to that group of people you don't kneed to enter anything there.

Comment: As you’re a reputation 11 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 0):

> Secure Shell (SSH) is a cryptographic network protocol for operating network services securely over an unsecured network. The best known example application is for remote login to computer systems by users.

If you don't connect remotely to another device or web services, you don't need ssh.

You can learn more in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) or [Ubuntu Community Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH).